# How to deploy a Maven Project from Eclipse IDE to Tomcat Server

Tags: maven-2

I have created a New Other --->Maven Project from Eclipse IDE 
and added Archetpe as 
org.apache.maven.archetypes --- maven-archetype-webapp 
and provided these values

Group Id : com.mypack
Artifact Id : MYWEBAPP
version : 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
package : com.mypack

Then from the command Prompt ,Went to that POM.xml directory ,and i have done these things

mvn clean
mvn install
mvn eclipse:eclipse

In all these cases the BUILD SUCCESSFUL came

Then from the Eclipse , i added the server Tomcat and wanted to install these MYWEBAPP to the server , but a  popup appeared saying

There are no resources that can be added or removed from the Server .

Please tell me if this is the correct procedure or not .

Answer (score 1):

A maven webapp unfortunately has a slightly different layout from an Eclipse webapp (WTP) project. The easiest way to get them to play nice together is do specify the [wtpversion](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html#wtpversion) parameter for the maven-eclipse plugin. This will ensure that when the Eclipse project settings are generated, it includes WTP settings, making your project a valid Eclipse webapp project which you can run directly from Eclipse.

Like so:

```
mvn -Dwtpversion=1.0 eclipse:eclipse
```